# How do I configure @KafkaListener to get the latest value for a key?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, debouncing

I send messages to Kafka that are keyed that way they will eventually be log compacted if it had the same key.

I was wondering how do you configure the `@KafkaListener` to get the most recent message for a given key assuming that the source may send updates frequently? Sort of like a `debounce` operator for Kafka so it waits for a few seconds of quiet after the last process.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. You'd need to know which exact offset the latest key was written to, then `seek` to it, but then that won't guarantee a newer key was not written by a producer after the seek.

Instead, [create a KTable](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/interactive-queries/) for the data. Then, when you query its statestore for any given key, it'll have the latest consumed value. From [Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_concepts_duality) - "A table can be considered a snapshot, at a point in time, **of the latest value for each key in a stream**".

Spring Cloud Stream's `InteractiveQueryService` can help with this

Answer (score 0):

See Consumer pausing feature:

> To safely pause and resume consumers, you should use the pause and resume methods on the listener containers. A `pause()` takes effect just before the next `poll()`; a `resume()` takes effect just after the current `poll()` returns.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#pause-resume

Comment: This stops consumption. How does that help get the latest key?

Comment: Correct , so you give some chance for Kafka to compact that topic before you pull what is the latest at that moment

Comment: But that's not guaranteed until the segment is closed. For example, if producing only 500 MB after a 1GB closed segment, that new segment will not be compacted and the consumer would still get duplicate keys

Comment: So, you mean that regular consumer is not OK for this kind of topics? What is an Apache Kafka recommendation then?

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: Huh? That’s Kafka Streams. The question was how to consume with regular Kafka Consumer…

Comment: So? Kafka Streams is built on top of regular Consumer API. It's not possible with the regular consumer for the above reason I mentioned unless using some in-memory datastructure to dedupe every consumed record key.

Comment: OK. It might be great if Apache Kafka would explain how to properly consume such a topic: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_compactionguarantees.

Comment: [_A table can be considered a snapshot, at a point in time, of **the latest value for each key in a stream**_](https://kafka.apache.org/32/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_concepts_duality)